# SonataMediaBundle SonataMediaProviderVideoBundle Argument 1 passed to FFMpeg\FFProbe::__construct() must be FFProbeDriver instance, array given

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I just installed the SonataMediaProviderVideoBundle and all related ones.

When i try to upload a video via the sonata media backend, I have this error (Sf 3.1.5):

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FFMpeg\FFProbe::__construct() must be an instance of FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver, array given, called in D:\wamp\www\test-sf3\TestSonata\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php

The array is taken from providers.yml line 41 https://github.com/xmon/SonataMediaProviderVideoBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/providers.yml

And here is the __construct which wait for the FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver instance at line 47 : on git hub -> PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/src/FFMpeg/FFProbe.php

Here is my stack trace:

```
Exception detected!
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FFMpeg\FFProbe::__construct() must be an instance of FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver, array given, called in D:\wamp\www\test-sf3\TestSonata\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 10246 and defined
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
Stack Trace

in vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe.php at line 47  -
        /** @var MapperInterface */
        private $mapper;
        public function __construct(FFProbeDriver $ffprobe, Cache $cache)
        {
            $this->ffprobe = $ffprobe;
            $this->optionsTester = new OptionsTester($ffprobe, $cache);
at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to FFMpeg\FFProbe::__construct() must be an instance of FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver, array given, called in D:\wamp\www\test-sf3\TestSonata\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 10246 and defined', 'D:\wamp\www\test-sf3\TestSonata\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe.php', '47', array())
in vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe.php at line 47  +
at FFProbe ->__construct (array('ffmpeg.binaries' => 'D:/wamp/bin/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe', 'ffprobe.binaries' => 'D:/wamp/bin/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe'), object(Logger))
in var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 10246  +
at appDevDebugProjectContainer ->getXmonFfmpeg_FfprobeService (false)
in var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 10237  +
at appDevDebugProjectContainer ->{closure} (null, object(FFMpegFFProbe_0000000055a8e24d00000000163507555ab0ef05b0b9e546824f0bb3e27d88c9), 'streams', array('pathfile' => 'D:\wamp\tmp\phpA9E3.tmp'), object(Closure))
in var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 13430  +
at Closure ->__invoke (null, object(FFMpegFFProbe_0000000055a8e24d00000000163507555ab0ef05b0b9e546824f0bb3e27d88c9), 'streams', array('pathfile' => 'D:\wamp\tmp\phpA9E3.tmp'), object(Closure))
in var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 13430  +
at FFMpegFFProbe_0000000055a8e24d00000000163507555ab0ef05b0b9e546824f0bb3e27d88c9 ->streams ('D:\wamp\tmp\phpA9E3.tmp')
in vendor\xmon\sonata-media-provider-video-bundle\Xmon\SonataMediaProviderVideoBundle\Provider\VideoProvider.php at line 142  +
at VideoProvider ->doTransform (object(Media))
in var\cache\dev\classes.php at line 17962  +
at BaseProvider ->transform (object(Media))
in vendor\sonata-project\media-bundle\Form\DataTransformer\ProviderDataTransformer.php at line 97  +
at ProviderDataTransformer ->reverseTransform (object(Media))
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 1057  +
at Form ->normToModel (object(Media))
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 633  +
at Form ->submit (array('providerName' => 'sonata.media.provider.video', 'thumbnailCapture' => '5', 'category' => '1', '_token' => 'CIunMwS122qjpqflpF4LSQH21TTztAPc0yeSHKtyuwE', 'binaryContent' => object(UploadedFile)), true)
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php at line 113  +
at HttpFoundationRequestHandler ->handleRequest (object(Form), object(Request))
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 488  +
at Form ->handleRequest (object(Request))
in vendor\sonata-project\admin-bundle\Controller\CRUDController.php at line 504  +
at CRUDController ->createAction ()
in vendor\sonata-project\media-bundle\Controller\MediaAdminController.php at line 39  +
at MediaAdminController ->createAction (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array (array(object(MediaAdminController), 'createAction'), array(object(Request)))
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 153  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 68  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php at line 169  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in web\app_dev.php at line 30  +
```

Comment: don't post images, paste the stacktrace as text properly formated (code) pls

Answer (score 1):

Solution found :

1 - I change the services in providers.yml to delete xmon_ffmpeg.ffmpeg et xmon_ffmpeg.ffprobe services. My service for the video provider is like this :

```
services:
    sonata.media.provider.video:
        class: %xmon_video.provider.video.class%
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.media.provider }
        arguments:
            - sonata.media.provider.video
            - '@sonata.media.filesystem.local'
            - '@sonata.media.cdn.server'
            - '@sonata.media.generator.default'
            - '@sonata.media.thumbnail.format'
            - [ mp4 ]
            - [ video/mp4 ]
            - '@sonata.media.resizer.custom'
            - '@sonata.media.metadata.proxy'
            - '@service_container'
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        calls:
            - [ setTemplates, [ { helper_thumbnail: XmonSonataMediaProviderVideoBundle:Provider:thumbnail.html.twig, helper_view: XmonSonataMediaProviderVideoBundle:Provider:video.html.twig } ] ]
```

2 - and i rewrite the constructor of VideoProvider.php like this :

```
 public function __construct($name, Filesystem $filesystem, CDNInterface $cdn, GeneratorInterface $pathGenerator, ThumbnailInterface $thumbnail, array $allowedExtensions = array(), array $allowedMimeTypes = array(), ResizerInterface $resizer, MetadataBuilderInterface $metadata = null, Container $container, EntityManager $entityManager) {
    ...

    $this->container = $container;
    $this->ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
        'ffmpeg.binaries' => $this->container->getParameter('xmon_ffmpeg.binary'), 
        'ffprobe.binaries' => $this->container->getParameter('xmon_ffprobe.binary'), 
        'timeout' => $this->container->getParameter('xmon_ffmpeg.binary_timeout'), 
        'ffmpeg.threads' => $this->container->getParameter('xmon_ffmpeg.threads_count')
    ]);
    $this->ffprobe =  FFProbe::create([
        'ffmpeg.binaries' => $this->container->getParameter('xmon_ffmpeg.binary'), 
        'ffprobe.binaries' => $this->container->getParameter('xmon_ffprobe.binary')
    ]);

    ...
}
```